# Contenteditable div , get form value options angular7

Tags: html, angular, angular6, contenteditable, angular-forms

Can I get true/false when I am typing content ? 
I have to show/hide submit button by using *ngIf option ?

When I am using form we use this `form.controls['name'].dirty`  it should be true or false

**My code** 
[stackblit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ac9ynz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<h5 contenteditable="true"(input)="issueTitle=$event.target.textContent" #titletag>Test </h5>
<button *ngIf="">submit</button>
```

Comment: `(ngModelChange)` with `[(ngModel)]`?

Comment: Didnt understand

Comment: Can you explain your requirement again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this.

**HTML**

```html
<h5 contenteditable="true" (keyup)="onKey($event)"> Test </h5>
<button *ngIf="isSubmitShow">submit</button>
```

**TS**

```
isSubmitShow: boolean = true;
onKey(data) {
 this.isSubmitShow = !this.isSubmitShow;
}
```